# Merging 2 Linkedlists in python NOT working. Third Linked List created is giving me a NULL value/result after execution

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm currently stuck on this python exercise where I have 2 LinkedLists (linked_list_1,linked_list_2) which I have to merge together in a new LinkedList. I have tried this code but it keeps giving me a null value for the third LinkedList when I need it to give me the data in both linkedLists. The function is called: merge_linked_lists(linked_list_1, linked_list_2). That's where my problem is. I would be really grateful if someone can help.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node, end=' ')
            node = node.next
        print('')

    def add_at_head(self, node):
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.length += 1

    def remove_node_after(self, node):
        if node.next is not None:
            temp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            temp.next = None
            self.length -= 1

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        temp.next = None
        self.length -= 1

    def print_backward(self):
        def print_nodes_backward(node):
            if node.next is not None:
                print_nodes_backward(node.next)
            if node is not None:
                print(node, end=' ')

        if self.head is not None:
            print_nodes_backward(self.head)

        print('')


def merge_linked_lists(linked_list_1, linked_list_2):
    def merge(List_1, List_2):
        head_ptr = temp_ptr = Node() # head_ptr will be the head node of the output list 
    # temp_ptr will be used to insert nodes in the output list
    
    # Loop for merging two lists
    # Loop terminates when both lists reaches to its end
        while List_1 or List_2:
            # List_1 has not reached its end
            # and List_2 has either reached its end or its current node has data
            # greater than or equal to the data of List_1 node
            # than insert List_1 node in the ouput list
            if List_1 and (not List_2 or List_1.data <= List_2.data):
                temp_ptr.next = Node(List_1.data)
                List_1 = List_1.next
            # otherwise insert List_2 node in the ouput list
            else:
                temp_ptr.next = Node(List_2.data)
                List_2 = List_2.next
            # move temp_pointer to next position
            temp_ptr = temp_ptr.next
        # return output list
        return head_ptr.next
    merge(linked_list_1.head, linked_list_2.head)


# Test merge() function
LL1 = LinkedList()
LL1.add_at_head(Node(2))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(4))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(6))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(8))
LL2 = LinkedList()
LL2.add_at_head(Node(1))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(3))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(5))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(7))
# Merge Function
LL3 = LinkedList()
LL3.head = merge_linked_lists(LL1, LL2)
LL3.print_list()
```

EDIT 1:

To anyone who wants to know the output, I tried this code on my IDE (Pycharm) and it gave an empty output/result. I also tried it on pythontutor (It visuals i/o there) and I saw that linked_list_1 and linked_list_2 haven't changed but the third linked list was null. Also during the execution, the third linkedlist was able to merge them together but it had an extra node which was the first node (head) and it had NONE as data.

EDIT 2:

The code finally worked!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node, end=' ')
            node = node.next
        print('')

    def add_at_head(self, node):
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.length += 1

    def remove_node_after(self, node):
        if node.next is not None:
            temp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            temp.next = None
            self.length -= 1

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        temp.next = None
        self.length -= 1

    def print_backward(self):
        def print_nodes_backward(node):
            if node.next is not None:
                print_nodes_backward(node.next)
            if node is not None:
                print(node, end=' ')

        if self.head is not None:
            print_nodes_backward(self.head)

        print('')

    def sortList(self):  
            #Node current will point to head  
            current = self.head;  
            index = None;  
              
            if(self.head == None):  
                return;  
            else:  
                while(current != None):  
                    #Node index will point to node next to current  
                    index = current.next;  
                      
                    while(index != None):  
                        #If current node's data is greater than index's node data, swap the data between them  
                        if(current.data > index.data):  
                            temp = current.data;  
                            current.data = index.data;  
                            index.data = temp;  
                        index = index.next;  
                    current = current.next;
                
def merge_linked_lists(linked_list_1, linked_list_2):
    linked_list_1.sortList()
    linked_list_2.sortList()
    def merge(List_1, List_2):
        head_ptr = temp_ptr = Node() # head_ptr will be the head node of the output list 
    # temp_ptr will be used to insert nodes in the output list
    
    # Loop for merging two lists
    # Loop terminates when both lists reaches to its end
        while List_1 or List_2:
            # List_1 has not reached its end
            # and List_2 has either reached its end or its current node has data
            # greater than or equal to the data of List_1 node
            # than insert List_1 node in the ouput list
            if List_1 and (not List_2 or List_2.data >= List_1.data):
                temp_ptr.next = Node(List_1.data)
                List_1 = List_1.next
            # otherwise insert List_2 node in the ouput list
            else:
                temp_ptr.next = Node(List_2.data)
                List_2 = List_2.next
            # move temp_pointer to next position
            temp_ptr = temp_ptr.next
        # return output list
        return head_ptr.next
    return merge(linked_list_1.head, linked_list_2.head)


# Test merge() function
LL1 = LinkedList()
LL1.add_at_head(Node(2))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(4))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(6))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(8))
LL2 = LinkedList()
LL2.add_at_head(Node(1))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(3))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(5))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(7))
# Merge Function
LL3 = LinkedList()
LL3.head = merge_linked_lists(LL1, LL2)
LL3.print_list()
```

Ps: I also made another code which also worked.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None

    def sortList(self):
        # Node current will point to head
        current = self.head;
        index = None;

        if (self.head == None):
            return;
        else:
            while (current != None):
                # Node index will point to node next to current
                index = current.next;

                while (index != None):
                    # If current node's data is greater than index's node data, swap the data between them
                    if (current.data < index.data):
                        temp = current.data;
                        current.data = index.data;
                        index.data = temp;
                    index = index.next;
                current = current.next;

    def print_list(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node, end=' ')
            node = node.next
        print('')

    def add_at_head(self, node):
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
        self.length += 1

    def remove_node_after(self, node):
        if node.next is not None:
            temp = node.next
            node.next = node.next.next
            temp.next = None
            self.length -= 1

    def remove_first_node(self):
        if self.head is None:
            return
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        temp.next = None
        self.length -= 1

    def print_backward(self):
        def print_nodes_backward(node):
            if node.next is not None:
                print_nodes_backward(node.next)
            if node is not None:
                print(node, end=' ')

        if self.head is not None:
            print_nodes_backward(self.head)

        print('')


def merge_linked_lists(linked_list_1, linked_list_2):
    linked_list_1.sortList()
    linked_list_2.sortList()
    LL3 = LinkedList()
    node = linked_list_2.head
    node1 = linked_list_1.head
    if node is None and node1 is None:
        return LL3
    while True:
        if node1 is None:
            LL3.add_at_head(Node(node.data))
            node = node.next
            if node is None:
                return LL3
            else:
                continue
        if node is None:
            LL3.add_at_head(Node(node1.data))
            node1 = node1.next
            if node1 is None:
                return LL3
            else:
                continue
        if node.data > node1.data:
            LL3.add_at_head(Node(node.data))
            node = node.next
        if node1.data > node.data:
            LL3.add_at_head(Node(node1.data))
            node1 = node1.next
    return LL3
# Test merge() function
# Linked List with even numbers
LL1 = LinkedList()
LL1.add_at_head(Node(2))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(4))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(6))
LL1.add_at_head(Node(8))
# Linked List with odd numbers
LL2 = LinkedList()
LL2.add_at_head(Node(1))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(3))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(5))
LL2.add_at_head(Node(7))
# Merge Function
LL3 = LinkedList()
LL3 = merge_linked_lists(LL1, LL2)
LL3.print_list()
```

Comment: Would you add the output of the code you've provided?

Comment: @Morgan, have you looked at answers? Do you still have the question?

Comment: @trincot yeah, I did. I tried changing <= to >= but it didn't work so I made another method/function called "sortList(self)" to sort the 2 linkedlists. I will add another edit with the code in it. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @trincot Could you please help me with my second question? I just posted that question a few minutes ago. This is the link for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64435957/python-lowest-k-elements-using-queue-not-working-with-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `merge` function has no return statement:

Change:

```
merge(linked_list_1.head, linked_list_2.head)
```

to:

```
return merge(linked_list_1.head, linked_list_2.head)
```

Another issue is that the sort order of your two input lists is descending, while your merge function assumes they are sorted ascending. So as a result your merged list is not sorted.

So either initialise your lists to be ascending in order (remember you insert values in reversed order) or change `<=` to `>=` in your merge function.