# Lowest-k elements using queue. Implementation does not pass test

Tags: python, queue

I need help with a python udemy exercise. This is the exercise:

> Write a function, given a list of integers, will give the k smallest
> integers contained in that list. The algorithm must not change the
> original array. Make the function as space-efficient as possible, so
> calling sort or sorted is not allowed. Generalize this to the
> k-smallest integers, assuming k << n, where n is the number of
> elements in the list
> *Hint: use a queue.*
>
> For example, lowest([1,2,3,-1,-2,-3],2) returns [-3,-2].

I tried this code and it works on Pycharm but it doesn't work on udemy and it keeps giving me:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sort'.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next_node

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.data)


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.length = 0
        self.head = None
        self.last = None

    def enqueue(self, data):
        node = Node(data)
        if self.length == 0:
            self.head = node
            self.last = node
            self.length = 1
            return
        last = self.last
        last.next = node
        self.last = node
        self.length += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.length == 0:
            return None
        data = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next
        self.length -= 1
        if self.length == 0:
            self.last = None
        return data


def lowest(l, k):
    if k >= (len(l)//2):
        return
    q = Queue()
    array = l.copy()
    while True:
        temp = max(array)
        q.enqueue(temp)
        array.remove(temp)
        if len(array) == k:
            return array


l = [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3]
print(lowest(l, 2))
l = [32,21,45,74,24,65,34,54,78,98,77,89,84]
print(lowest(l,9))
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! `sorted` is just as space efficient as a queue, if not better if you're allowed the mutate the parameter list. Not sure I understand the requirements here. As for your error, are you returning/printing the result correctly in the format expected by the runner? I ask because your code doesn't use `.sort` anywhere, so it's probably in the boilerplate code.

Comment: You should remove `if k >= (len(l)//2): return` from your code, as your function should never return *None*.

Comment: @trincot I already tried that but it didn't work. It gave me this error --> "max() arg is an empty sequence"

Comment: That is a different problem: you assume that the array is always non-empty, but this error shows that there is a test with an empty array. Your code should be able to deal with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not always returning a list:

```
if k >= (len(l)//2):
    return
```

The condition in the `if` might be true, and then you return `None`. For instance, if `l` is empty (and by consequence `k` is zero), this condition will be true and your code returns `None` instead of the expected `[]`.

So remove that `if` block.

Secondly, your code will still fail when `l` is empty, because the argument of `max()` must be non-empty.

Instead of putting an `if` inside the loop that determines when the loop should end, put the condition in the `while` condition:

```
def lowest(l, k):
    q = Queue()
    array = l.copy()
    while k < len(array):
        temp = max(array)
        q.enqueue(temp)
        array.remove(temp)
    return array
```

It should be noted however, that this solution is no better in space usage than a solution that would use `sorted`. If you really want to follow the restrictions in the challenge, this should not count as a solution. This code copies the whole input array, and so uses *O(n)* extra space.

There are ways to only use *O(k)* extra space, which is the space needed to return the result. Although the description of the challenge hints to use a queue, I would opt for a max heap which never exceeds *k* entries.